# ADB Restore Stalling on "Full Backup" screen

Tags: adb, restore, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I just upgraded from a Galaxy Note 4 running Android 6.0 to a Galaxy S8+ running 7.0.  Neither is rooted.  I've used Helium in the past to backup app data. However it's crashing or just not working when I'm trying to restore to the S8+.

I'm trying to use ADB directly to restore the ab files.  I found that the phone is getting stuck on a screen titled "Full Backup" (see below).  A) it says my device is encrypted.  Is it?  I didn't turn on encryption.  B) The "Back Up My Data" button is grayed out unless I enter a password.

I believe this may be the same issue breaking Helium.  What does this mean?  How do I restore backups?

(I still have the Note 4 in moderately good working condition, so I can recreate backup files if necessary)

[image]

Comment: It's not your device that is encrypted. Setting up a password is mandatory as I recall